# Multiple partial word search not working

Tags: content-search, solr

I have implemented a global search on our website which gets the data result from _content field in solr indexes.

Single word search works perfectly fine but I am currently facing an issue if I have two or more words but the second word is partial. example

If I search "thrill" - search works fine.

If I search "thri" - search works fine and gives me the result of content which contains thril.

If I search "thrill rides" - search works fine

but if I search "thrill ri" or "thrill rid"- it does not return any result where I am expecting the result pages which contains "thrill rides"

It is the second partial string which does not work

I tried searching the same query inside the Sitecore content manager and it gives me the same result as on my website

So I am thinking that it is not something related in the code (below) but in the configuration.

```
      var startItem = sitecoreContext.GetHomeItem<Item>();
    using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(new SitecoreIndexableItem(startItem)).CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();                    
        filterPredicate = filterPredicate.And(x => x.Content.Contains(queryItem)).Or(x => x.Name.Contains(queryItem));
        var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Filter(filterPredicate);
                    }
```

may be I need to add some configuration in

```
<analyzer type="index"> in schema.xml
```

Currently it has default settings

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />       
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: which version of solr you are using? can you also show the code snippet which you are using to search the _content field?

Comment: Hi, solr version is 5.1.0 and code is pretty straight forward. I have added the code above but the results for example "thrill ri" is not appearing in content editor as well which is coming from sitecore dll so I believe it is something in  the configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it is mentioned in documentation, Solr does not support the wildcard query (this is a type of query to which `.contains("phrase")` will be converted) for search phrases:

> Solr’s standard query parser supports single and multiple character wildcard searches within single terms. Wildcard characters can be applied to single terms, but not to search phrases. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html

When you try to search `"thri"`, your query is parsed as `<str name="parsed query">content:thri</str>` and Solr searches for `"thri"` as a part of word or an entire word.

But when you try to search `"thrill rid"`, your query is parsed as `<str name="parsedquery">PhraseQuery(_content:"thrill rid")</str>`. In this case, Solr searches of containing the `"thrill"` and `"rid"` just as entire words in the document and you don't get any results, because you don't have a document with `"rid"`.

The easiest way to supporting multi word search with search by the part of word is to apply the code like below:

```
var querySplitted = queryItem.Split(' '); //Split the queryItem by the white space (or any other symbols if you need)

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<TIndexModel>();

var namePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TIndexModel>();
var contentPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TIndexModel>();

foreach (var query in querySplitted)
{

     namePredicate = namePredicate.And(item => item.Name.Contains(query).Boost(1.5f));
     contentPredicate = contentPredicate.And(item => item.Content.Contains(query));
}

predicate = predicate.Or(namePredicate).Or(contentPredicate);

var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Filter(predicate);
```

The code above works as you expect.

Another way is to change the **tokenizer**.

Currently, you use the `StandardTokenizerFactory` for both *"index"* and "query" analyzers. This tokenizer splits your `"thrill rides"` into two words: `"thrill", "rides"`.

If you want to search by parts of a word, you need apply, for example, [N-Gram Tokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer), `<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="5"/>`,  which will devide your `"thrill rides"` phrase to the foolowing parts: `thri thril hril hrill rill rill ill ill rid rid ride ride rides ides`. In this case you will be able to search by the part of word.
You need apply the `NGramTokenizerFactory` for both analyzers:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="5"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="5"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

In case of using NGramTokenizerFactory, you need to use `==` operator instead of `.Contains()`. For example: `predicate.Or(item => item.Name == query)`.

> In case you change the analyzer to NGramTokenizerFactory be careful as the size of index will increase and potentially **can cause a performance issue**. I recommend you think twice before changing of analyzer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but this way it separate the two strings and give me the results for both of them. example it is searching for pages which has "ride" only not thrill ride. Can solr search full contain string showing only result for pages which has "thrill ri" full string contains in it. thanks

Comment: I dissagree with you. The example which I've provided returns results that contains both "thrill" and "ri" keywords. I can see that there are AND operators in predicates: `namePredicate = namePredicate.And(item => item.Name.Contains(query).Boost(1.5f));`
     `contentPredicate = contentPredicate.And(item => item.Content.Contains(query));`

Comment: I tried testing it again and I realised that it is because of of name of items it was including those results. Yes, contains works fine. Thank you. Just one more thing I need to ask you is that I am trying to remove the Item Name search filter from query but it is still giving me the results of item which has the item name as the query?

Comment: @Meenakshi it happens because the `content` field accumulates values of each field with the text value, including the item name field. Please see the following question where this was discussed: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8609/what-class-indexes-the-content-index-field/8610?noredirect=1#comment13133_8610