# Large folder with images created on reindex: \App_Data\mediaIndexing

Tags: media-library, indexing

When reindexing on Sitecore 9.1, a folder with all the images is created `..\App_Data\mediaIndexing`. My problem is that it gets very big in size, > 55GB of images in my case. Has anyone encountered this problem because I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: interesting! I have never seen mediaIndexing folder :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done as part of the extraction of the content of media items for the `_content` field. See for example `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` where it has the type `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch`. The file mapping is done in the node at `contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing`. If you would like to disable this, you could create a patch file to remove this field. Something like:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <patch:delete />
              </field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Only thing I would add is to be a little careful about removing `fieldName="_content"` because it is often augmented by custom computed indexers for indexing datasources for exmaple (e.g. https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/). It might be safer to target the `type` attribute in the patch.

Comment: Ah, good call, didn't realize people were doing that. Not sure I like the idea of adding multiple entries for `_content`, but if people are doing it, so be it.

Comment: That field is used internally and already has indexed data added to it, so it is not uncommon to further augment that data: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8609/what-class-indexes-the-content-index-field

Comment: Thank you @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain.
Yes, I had to change the fieldName (_content) with type (Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch) and it worked.

Comment: @Ivana That's great. If you don't mind, please go ahead and accept this answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Shall we conclude that this is temporary data used during the indexing process and can therefore be cleaned up frequently?  There is a scheduled cleanup process that can be used to achieve this easily enough I think